# Big scope of Azure Resources is mentioned by ARM deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps Pipeline to deploy ARM Templates for Alerts and Workbooks in Azure Monitoring. The problem is, every time the pipeline is running, many resources are mentioned is Pipeline. The status of them is 'ignored', so they are not getting changed, but they are mentioned every time. I do not understand why they are mentioned and what if one day they will be changed, which will break the whole infrastructure?
I am using Subscription scope to deploy ARM Templates.
This is how it looks like:

```
Resource and property changes are indicated with these symbols:
  = Nochange
  * Ignore

The deployment will update the following scope:

Scope: /subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***

  = microsoft.insights/metricalerts/***
  * Microsoft.Compute/diskEncryptionSets/***
  * Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys/***
  * Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/***
  * Microsoft.Insights/scheduledqueryrules/***
  * Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/***
  * Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/***
  * Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/***/virtualNetworkLinks/***
  * Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/***/virtualNetworkLinks/***
  * Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/***
  * Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions/ContainerInsights(***)
  * microsoft.insights/metricalerts/***
    ...
  * microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules/***
  * microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules/***
  * microsoft.insights/workbooks/***
  * microsoft.insights/workbooks/***

Resource changes: 1 no change, 21 to ignore.
Finishing: ARM deployment plan
```

Thank you!

I am especially confused about mentioned diskEncryptionSets, sshPublicKeys and privateDnsZones. What does it have to do with Alerts and Workbooks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *ignored* resources represent resources that are present within the scope of the deployment (in this case within the target subscription) but are not defined within the current ARM template.

See the [manual page on what-if deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell#change-types) for reference.

Resource that *are* defined within the template but are in compliance with the template will show as *NoChange*.